# Can't connect to Aurora MySQL DB

Tags: amazon-aurora

i keep getting error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'10.1.17.202'

I am trying to connect from an EC2 within the same VPC as the Aurora RDS. Its a serverless RDS cluster.

Comment: what type of authentication are you using , user/name password , or IAM ?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you are using to connect are not correct. Ensure you are using the same username and password that were configured when the RDS database was created. The error is not related to VPC or security groups.

If you forgot the password then you can reset it by modifying the database in the RDS console.

Answer (score 0):

The CIDR blocks you are using for the inbound rules are probably not correct.